# Css Banner Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am starting to learn css and html and on my website I made a banner that looks like this: [image]

I was wondering if it is possible to take this example I made and transform it in a banner with a slider with up to 3 images, like this:
[image]

I imagine that it isn't possible with only css, but I know nothing about javascript, I tried a lot of tutorials of sliders but none looked the way I wanted, which is a banner with 100% width.

**Can someone help me transform the first image into the second one?**

**My code:**

**html:** `<div id="banner" class="banner"></div>`

**css:**

```
.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    background: url("http://s2.postimg.org/vtiiv9maf/index_banner.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**jsfiddle** example of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/wykknyqf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use Bootstrap Carousel? http://jsfiddle.net/mm6ck3dc/5/

**HTML**

```
 <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>

    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="Chania" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="Chania" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="Flower" height="345">
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  body{margin: 0;}
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
  }
```

Comment: go here for documenation   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a simple slider that will roate your images.** 
http://jsfiddle.net/EPXuH/42/

Just replace the image link + size, etc.

```
<img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6238/6362150571_5268f71c2f.jpg" alt="some more alt text" width="500" height="500" />
```

If you arent sure how to make and link a .js file to your document. I suggest wrapping the js in a `<script> </script>` tag in your html document.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I'd suggest to use a slider plugin/library. Coding a slider is, as far as I know, first of all not possible with CSS only. Further writing one yourself without any javascript knowledge will be pretty hard for you.

here are two cool javascript/jquery plugins you can use:

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

https://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Just overwrite the styles in CSS and adjust their settings in the corrosponding js-files to make them fit your needs.